# Массив функций: можно ли реализовать?

Tags: c++, массивы

Можно ли в C++ реализовать массив функций? То есть, в массив можно записать функции `a()`, `b()` и `c()` (не сами функции, а операторы для их вызова), а затем вызывать их, как будет удобно. Если нет, то можно вызывать ту функцию, которая указана в аргументах?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я долго в оффлайне был.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В современном c++ присутствуют удобные средства для оперирования функциями как функциональными объектами. Посмотрите [functional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/), а именно [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) и [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/). По указанным ссылкам также находятся очень хорошие примеры.

Разумеется в c++ можно работать и с голыми указателями на функции (свободные и функции-члены класса), но это не так удобно и просто. Особенно при построении пользовательского интерфейса.

Пример массива функций. В качестве массива используем стандартный контейнер [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/). Ниже продемонстрировано как можно для более узкой сигнатуры функции использовать более широкое определение. Известно что вызывающая сторона ожидает сигнатуру void(int), а мы будем ей передавать `void(int, int)` и `void(const std::string&, int, int)`.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::bind
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void a(int x, int y) 
{
  std::cout << "a(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
void b(int x, int y) 
{
  std::cout << "b(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
void c(const std::string& s, int x, int y) 
{
  std::cout << "c(" << s << ", " << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main () {
  using namespace std::placeholders;    // adds visibility of _1, _2, _3,...

  std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> functions;

  // создаем и помещаем в вектор функциональный объект, во время вызова необходимо передать один аргумент
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(a, _1, _1));
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(a, _1, 42));
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(a, _1, 100500));
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(b, _1, 42));
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(b, 42, _1));
  functions.emplace_back(std::bind(c, "Hello world!", _1, 3));

  int i = 0;
  for (const auto& fn : functions) {
    fn(i++);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Вывод.

```
a(0, 0)
a(1, 42)
a(2, 100500)
b(3, 42)
b(42, 4)
c(Hello world!, 5, 3)
```

Еще один пример (взят с [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/)):

```
// bind example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::bind

// a function: (also works with function object: std::divides<double> my_divide;)
double my_divide (double x, double y) {return x/y;}

struct MyPair {
  double a,b;
  double multiply() {return a*b;}
};

int main () {
  using namespace std::placeholders;    // adds visibility of _1, _2, _3,...

  // binding functions:
  auto fn_five = std::bind (my_divide,10,2);               // returns 10/2
  std::cout << fn_five() << '\n';                          // 5

  auto fn_half = std::bind (my_divide,_1,2);               // returns x/2
  std::cout << fn_half(10) << '\n';                        // 5

  auto fn_invert = std::bind (my_divide,_2,_1);            // returns y/x
  std::cout << fn_invert(10,2) << '\n';                    // 0.2

  auto fn_rounding = std::bind<int> (my_divide,_1,_2);     // returns int(x/y)
  std::cout << fn_rounding(10,3) << '\n';                  // 3

  MyPair ten_two {10,2};

  // binding members:
  auto bound_member_fn = std::bind (&MyPair::multiply,_1); // returns x.multiply()
  std::cout << bound_member_fn(ten_two) << '\n';           // 20

  auto bound_member_data = std::bind (&MyPair::a,ten_two); // returns ten_two.a
  std::cout << bound_member_data() << '\n';                // 10

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы бы включили сюда примеры и объяснение, а то ссылки имеют обыкновение умирать.

Comment: Раз уж начали,то и продолжайте описывать по русски содержимое ссылок на bind (как им пользоваться) и т.п.

Comment: Пожалуй, это мне и нужно.

Answer (score 8):

Конечно можно!

```
double (*funcs_array[64])(int a, float b);
```

Однако обычно, чтобы не запутаться, я объявляю тип указателя на функцию отдельным псевдонимом. Тогда объявление массива таких указателей не отличается от объявления массива либого другого типа.

```
typedef double (*FuncPtr)(int a, float b);

FuncPtr funcs_array[64];
```

Про указатели на функции неплохой стартовый пост был у [Алены](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2007/04/blog-post.html).

Comment: Я просто собрался его делать для того, чтобы реализовать динамическую работу с окнами в своей библиотеке. А массив функций - одна из тех вещей, которая мне нужна для этого.  Вторая такая вещь - "дефрагментация" массива, которую я сам напишу, а третья - многопоточность, которую я начал изучать в последнее время.

Comment: Ещё бы без typedef'а примерчик :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, `double (*funcs_array[64])(int a, float b);`

Answer (score 4):

Имя функции в Си++ - это такой же указатель как и все прочие. Соответственно можно собрать их в массив. Главное с аргументами не перемудрить

Answer (score 2):

Конечно можно создавать массивы функций и вызывать их из массива. Посмотрите мой код с комментариями как это делается.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Создаем три функции с одинаковым количеством параметров
// и соответствующими типами, а так же возращаемым типом
int sum(const int a, const int b){
    return a + b;
}

int sep(const int a, const int b){
    return a - b;
}

int mul(const int a, const int b){
    return a * b;
}

typedef // создаем новый прототип (в данном случае указатель на функцию)
        int // возвращаемое значение (такое же как в функциях)
            (*func) // имя прототипа (в коде употребляется без звездочки)
                   (const int, const int); // список параметров (такое же как в функциях)

int main(){
    func arr[3]; // обьявляем массив функций из трех элементов

    // помещаем в массив функции указывая их имена (потому что имя функции это и есть указатель на нее)
    arr[0] = sum;
    arr[1] = sep;
    arr[2] = mul;

    // используем указатели из массива (выводим результат функций в массиве с конкретными параметрами)
    cout << arr[0](5, 2) << endl;
    cout << arr[1](5, 2) << endl;
    cout << arr[2](5, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот код и на линуксе так же себя поведет. а то что вы виндовый дизайн окон не любите так это ваша проблема

Comment: @Linuxoid: Быть пользователем Линукса ещё не означает преимущества над другими.